# TypeScript generic type check changes behavior of the type when passed in enum

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, typescript-generics

I encountered the following problem:

```js
type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;

enum TestEnum {
    T1 = "T1",
    T2 = "T2",
}

interface Data {
    Val: TestEnum;
}

type AltFormData<T> = T extends object
    ? {
          readonly [P in keyof T]-?: AltFormData<NonUndefined<T[P]>>;
      } & AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>>
    : AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>>;

type Alt1FormData<T> = AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>>;

type Alt2FormData<T> = T extends object ? AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>> : AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>>;

type AltFormValue<T = any> = {
    readonly $setValue: (value: T | undefined) => void;
};

const x2: AltFormData<Data> = {};
x2.Val.$setValue(TestEnum.T1); // ERROR - x2.Val is of type AltFormValue<TestEnum.T1> | AltFormValue<TestEnum.T2> and should be of type AltFormValue<TestEnum>

const x3: AltFormValue<TestEnum> = {};
x3.$setValue(TestEnum.T1); // GOOD

const x4: AltFormData<TestEnum> = {};
x4.$setValue(TestEnum.T1); // ERROR - x4 is of type AltFormValue<TestEnum.T1> | AltFormValue<TestEnum.T2> and should be of type AltFormValue<TestEnum>

const x5: AltFormValue<NonUndefined<TestEnum>> = {};
x5.$setValue(TestEnum.T1); // GOOD

const x6: Alt1FormData<TestEnum> = {};
x6.$setValue(TestEnum.T1); // GOOD

const x7: Alt2FormData<TestEnum> = {};
x7.$setValue(TestEnum.T1); // ERROR - x7 is of type AltFormValue<TestEnum.T1> | AltFormValue<TestEnum.T2> and should be of type AltFormValue<TestEnum>
```

It seems that type check `T extends object` is somehow changing the result. Same thing happends when using type `"T1" | "T2"` instead of enum. You can copy and paste this code into the TS Playground or just click on the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwKoICYQGYEsEVQHgBUA+KAXikKggA9gI0BnKAVzUxzygH4pcA3CACcoALkoBuAFBSGLALaUIjYAFEECqAG8pUPZQCM5KACJCBkwBpd+wgCZjZu1akBfGTnpCMAQwDG0AAiPsA+2jZ6AGo+ADbihMpqGvLS7lKgkFAAgjHAAGJwQvLBoUSkFFS09ExQcABGAFYQfsARPOH6nfpCED6oiDEgUADaAApQOFAA1hAgcBiUALoAtNziOfmFxSE++PDI7Ni4BIRji8TE0l1QrlAAZNm5BUXRMSwQe4go6Ed4ZcRtdZPLavd6fA4-TgnC7SdLgaAbAzPbalEjGDbI0EffbfDjHf6wjII3J2ZElXZoirUOgMVDMepNFrtDEg2JgnGHKH-MSPTYvNnYr6c-EkS4yIm8zECojGHwIEDlDrdXr9BCDKAAEkYEGAWPEAAp+AL4lAAD6sYV4ACU5FI-DgWFQqVhfkQKigNDsQL5KN25MVWlc0k9ADpXiGtTqsfqEip1AoQ+YrRIoAB6VNQVQAJSzAHks1Blh67GHYhN6QsJSz+W8PrGkgnzKRzdX5FiiIl4-JE3ZSHLUFBGAALOAsGIDurQeZQKvAmtg+tdgFSV0Id00ADM3qltY7ceSAaDUk3Ee1uoFMc7yUTBmTaYzAHFc7nAjJV+uACzbrbkvcN+SHsGH6nlGF6LteSYpummY5vmhYeh+5a1JW8KSqyu7gY2BjNmh851leja9lA-aDiOY4TlOKGZK27aYQBb5usAHoAKzfnh4K4r8JwEQBgHHsxIHnrWl77lhd7QU+L4MWuTE0AAbN6SI-jsf5LsYgbBnJgnRnRN7iY+z6viujEegA7N6pLKaiPF8TQpnaWBPF6VBGbZnmBZFnZSHTrOPq0U5TZmrhbbSrp9h9mgpGjuOUCTshM6oTRoU2UAA).

Comment: What is the question here? Are the errors unexpected?

Comment: Yes, they are unexpected. How can I change the type definitions so the examples that are giving me an error stop giving me an error? It should be all the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like typescript is treating the `enum` type as union of it's values really. This has consequences for conditional types.

So, when you have this type:

```
type Alt2FormData<T> = T extends object ? AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>> : AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>>;
```

And you will feed it the enum, which is really `TestEnum.T1 | TestEnum.T2`, typescript will actually compute the type.

```
AltFormValue<NonUndefined<TestEnum.T1>> | AltFormValue<NonUndefined<TestEnum.T2>>
```

This is call [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), the default how typescript is treating union types in conditionals.
If you don't want that, you need to turn off this by wrapping `T` and `object` into brackets.

```
type Alt2FormData<T> = [T] extends [object] ? AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>> : AltFormValue<NonUndefined<T>>;
```

This will result into this type to be computed instead:

```
AltFormValue<NonUndefined<TestEnum.T1 | TestEnum.T2>>
```

If you simplify, then this is the desired type

```
AltFormValue<NonUndefined<TestEnum>>
```

which is alias for:

```
{
    readonly $setValue: (value: TestEnum | undefined) => void;
}
```

Then you shouldn't see the compilation errors.